# Rotating Poly with transformation matrix.Figure is getting deformed

Tags: java, user-interface, matrix, graphics, point

I'm relatively new in Java and I have a task to realize the rotation of a figure drawn from random points. The realization has to be written by means of "naked logic", so AffineTransform tools is not an option in this case. And I got stuck in a moment where I suppose to translate shape to origin in order to perform rotation. I racked my brains, surfed on the internet but couldn't succeed with the solution. There is already one topic with a similar issue, tho there it was about rectangles translation, so it hasn't worked for me. Maybe someone could help with this.

public class Frame extends JFrame  {

```
private JButton polyBtn = new JButton("Draw/Redraw Poly");
private JButton rotationBtn = new JButton("Rotate");
private JSpinner polySpn = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(3,3,10,1));
private JSpinner angleSpn = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,360,1));
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
private JLabel polyLbl = new JLabel("Choose number of corners");
private JLabel angleLbl = new JLabel("Choose angle of rotation");
private int cornerAmount , degree ;
private boolean figureIsDrawed = false;
Random r = new Random();
Polygon poly = new Polygon();
Polygon editedPoly = new Polygon();


public Frame() {

    super("Rotate Object");
    setBounds(100, 100, 500, 250);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container container = this.getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);

    polyBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cornerAmount = (int) polySpn.getValue();
            drawPoly(cornerAmount);

        }});

    rotationBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            degree = (int) angleSpn.getValue();
            rotateShape(degree);

        }});

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,250));
    panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black,3));

    controlPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));
    controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,0,0,0));

    polyLbl.setFont(polyLbl.getFont().deriveFont(10.0f));
    angleLbl.setFont(angleLbl.getFont().deriveFont(10.0f));

    controlPanel.add(polyLbl);
    controlPanel.add(polySpn);
    controlPanel.add(polyBtn);

    controlPanel.add(angleLbl);
    controlPanel.add(angleSpn);
    controlPanel.add(rotationBtn);

    container.add(controlPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    container.add(panel,BorderLayout.EAST);
}

private void drawPoly(int corners) {
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    int panelWidth = panel.getWidth();
    int panelHeight = panel.getHeight();

    if(figureIsDrawed) {
        poly.reset();
        repaint();
        figureIsDrawed = false;
    }else {
        poly.addPoint(panelWidth/2, panelHeight/2);
        System.out.println(poly.xpoints[0]);
        System.out.println(poly.ypoints[0]);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < corners-1 ; i++) {
            poly.addPoint(r.nextInt(panelWidth), r.nextInt(panelHeight));               
        }
        g.drawPolygon(poly);
        figureIsDrawed = true;
    }
}
private void rotateShape(int degree) {
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    int[] xCord = poly.xpoints;
    int[] yCord = poly.ypoints;
    double rads = degree * (Math.PI/180);
    double sin =  Math.sin(rads);
    double cos =  Math.cos(rads);
    double[][] transform = new double[3][3];
    int panelW = this.getWidth();
    int panelH = this.getHeight();
    transform[0][0] = cos;
    transform[0][1] = -sin;
    transform[1][0] = sin;
    transform[1][1] = cos;

    double[] transformedX = new double[xCord.length];
    double[] transformedY = new double[yCord.length];

    int[] updatedX = new int[xCord.length];
    int[] updatedY = new int[yCord.length];
    for(int i = 0;i<updatedX.length;i++) {
        updatedX[i] = xCord[i];
        updatedY[i] = yCord[i];
        transformedX[i] = Math.round(updatedX[i] * transform[0][0] + updatedY[i] * transform[0][1] + transform[0][2]);
        transformedY[i] = Math.round( updatedX[i] * transform[1][0] + updatedY[i] * transform[1][1] + transform[1][2]);
        updatedX[i] = (int)transformedX[i];
        updatedY[i] = (int)transformedY[i];
    }
    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, panelW, panelH);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawPolygon(updatedX, updatedY, updatedX.length); 
}
```

}

The main problem is in "RotateShape" method.I just can't figure out,how to make it work right.

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistake in your rotation. The only thing that could cause this (depending on how many rotations you perform) is the rounding to integer. Rounding should only be performed as a final (temporary) step before drawing. Not in between operations that require more precision.

Comment: But isn't rounding to integer already a final operation before painting? Well, during transformation there appears unwanted extra dot tied to the origin, which causes the shape to deform rather than rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Your rotation code is correct. But you are trying to transform more points than there are in the polygon. The internal `xpoints` and `ypoints` arrays are not necessarily filled completely. Replace all occurences of `xCord.length` and `yCord.length` with `poly.npoints` and you are good to go.